# ¿Cómo utilizar sonarqube con c#?

Tags: c#, sonar

Tengo una duda con sonarqube. Logré correrlo, pero ahora quiero probar el analisis de proyectos de c#.

Estaba siguiendo la guía https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900 pero honestamente no entendí muy bien, descargué el plugin, lo metí en la carpeta de plugins, pero después honestamente no entendí muy bien qué tenía que hacer.

Les agradecería la ayuda, según leí, en otro foro, tenía que correr el sonar como un servicio de windows, pero eso tampoco me deja, sólo dice que se ejecutó pero se detuvo al iniciar.

La consulta es: ¿cómo puedo utilizar la herramienta para c#?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bueno, después de mucho leer, encontré como ejecutarlo para c#.

Para empezar, tenemos que descargarnos la última versión del sonarqube de aquí:

https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/

Luego, tenemos que descargar el SonarMSBuild de aquí:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+MSBuild

y por último nos descargamos el plugin para c# de aquí:

https://docs.sonarqube.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1441900

NOTA: Yo recomiendo por comodidad, descomprimir el sonar y el sonarMSBuild en la raíz de tu disco ya que tendremos que ejecutarlo por linea de comandos.

Para empezar, instalamos el sonarqube como un servicio en la PC, esto lo hacemos ejecutando el siguiente comando en tu cmd/PowerShell (hay que abrir la linea de comando como administrador):

```
C:\sonarqube-6.7.1\bin\windows-x86-64\InstallNTService.bat
```

De esta manera nos queda instalado como un servicio. En mi caso la arquitectura de mi computadora es de 64 bits por eso la ruta ...\windows-x86-64...

Luego, para iniciar el servicio ejecutamos el siguiente comando:

```
C:\sonarqube-6.7.1\bin\windows-x86-64\StartNTService.bat
```

Listo, una vez iniciado, verificamos en nuestro navegador entrando a la URL:

```
localhost:9000
```

OJO!!!: Si te sale que inició el servicio y no puede entrar a la URL, presiona las teclas windows+R y escribe services.msc, luego, dar clic a aceptar, en la lista que nos aparece, buscamos SonarQube, le damos clic derecho e iniciar.

Este paso lo pueden llevar a cabo en el inicio o a en este momento y es copiar y pegar el plugin descargado de c# en la carpeta de sonarqube, extensions, plugins.

Listo ahora vamos a lo que nos interesa, analizar el proyecto.

Para ello, nos vamos a la ruta raíz del proyecto desde la consola (asegurense que el servicio esté corriendo), por ejemplo:

cd 'C:\Users\Alex\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication1'

Una vez en la raíz del proyecto, ejecutamos:

```
 C:\SonarQube-Scanner-for-MSBuild\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe begin /k:"ConsoleApplication1" /n:"ConsoleApplication1" /v:"1.0"
```

Una vez les salga el mensaje: "Pre-processing succeded", lo que vamos a ejecutar la siguiente línea:

MSBuild.exe /t:Rebuild

Si esto les da error, es porque no tienen configurada la variable de entorno para eso, pero en ese caso sólo tienen que hacerlo manual, es decir:

```
'C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe' /t:Rebuild
```

una vez terminada la compilación del proyecto, basta con decirle al programa mediante la línea de comandos que ejecute el analisis hasta el fin. Esto lo hacemos así:

```
C:\SonarQube-Scanner-for-MSBuild\SonarQube.Scanner.MSBuild.exe end
```

Y listo, una vez termine de ejecutarse esta línea de código, basta con entrar a la ruta que mencioné anteriormente, localhost:9000 y podremos ver los datos de nuestro analisis.

Algo largo, pero espero les ayude un poco :D

Comment: ¿como seteas otro server y no localhost?